# Bind checkbox value based on a component value angular2

Tags: angular

I have checkbox like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="SDC"  checked (click)="toggle(1)">S</label>
<input type="radio" name="SDC" (click)="toggle(2)">D</label>
```

I get value from database in the component page which will decide which checkbox is checked.

```
this.details[0].Type -- returns 1 or 2
```

If it is 1 then 1st radiobutton should get checked else the second one.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="SDC" [attr.checked]="details && details[0]?.Type=='1'" (click)="toggle(1)"><label>S</label>
<input type="radio" [attr.checked]="details && details[0]?.Type=='2'" name="SDC" (click)="toggle(2)"><label>D</label>
```

Try something like this to set the checked attribute

Comment: This is a nice solution but for the first load, I do not have any call for details, hence it is blank and I get get error. How can I check if details is there, use this else let it be checked or unchecked by default